# DB2 Query Joins

Tags: join, db2

I hope you can help with this, I have two vehicle tables in DB2, OR and OS, OR is where the orders for the cars that are going to be delivered are, and OS are those cars that are already sold,want to consult the all the orders in the OR table but NOT the ones that are cancelled in the OS table, I identify the cancelled ones by their status ('8'), I tried with this query, but the orders I get are only the ones in the OS table, not all the orders are in the OS table, I tried with an OUTER JOIN but it's not the result I expected.

```
SELECT OR.OBNO, OR.ORSC, OS.SCLD
FROM
TABLE.OR LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE.OS ON OR.OBNO=OS.OBNO 
WHERE OS.SLCD NOT IN ('8')
```

this only gets me the all the orders in the OS table and excluding the ones in the OR table (the OR table does not have  SLCD status, I want to exclude all the orders that have an 8 status in the OS table but keeping the ones that are not in the OS table).

This one is the same result.

```
SELECT OR.OBNO, OR.ORSC, OS.SCLD
FROM
TABLE.OR LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE.OS ON OR.OBNO=OS.OBNO AND OS.SLCD NOT IN ('8')
```

I hope someone can help me. thanks a lot

Comment: Your second try is wrong and will not deliver the same result. The first looks good for me but I cannot understand fully what you think is wrong with it. As it is a left join it will return all the rows of your left table - which is OR but you wrote "all the orders in the OS table " .

Comment: Yes, I thought the left outer join will return all the rows in OR table but in this case only returns the orders that are in the OS table with the SLCD status, I want to retrieve too the data of the orders that are ONLY in the OR table, when I put the NOT IN condition is when I have the problem, it is not returning the orders that are only in the OR table. I appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an alternative way of retrieving these data:

```
SELECT OR.OBNO, OR.ORSC, OS.SCLD
FROM TABLE.OR WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE.OS WHERE OR.OBNO=OS.OBNO AND OS.SLCD = '8')
```

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio I tried the query you mention but it retrieves no data, I tried your query on another way since the way you mention gives me an error: SELECT PFOR.ORNO, PFOR.ORSC, PFOS.SLCD
FROM
LPMXPFIL.PFOR PFOR INNER JOIN LPMXPFIL.PFOS PFOS ON PFOR.ORNO=PFOS.OBNO
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT PFOS.SLCD FROM LPMXPFIL.PFOS PFOS PFOS.SLCD = '8')